# Add file name and line to ruby ActiveSupport BufferedLogger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, logging, activesupport

I'm using ActiveSupport::BufferedLogger to write logs in a Rails app like this:

`Rails.logger.info "My Message"`

which prints a line into the logs like this:

`2014-07-28 16:20:03.288 [INFO ] My Message`

I would like to modify the logger so that it prints the file_name and line_number from where the call to Rails.logger.info was made, so it should print something like this:

`2014-07-28 16:20:03.288 [INFO ] myprogram.rb:34 - My Message`

I tried overriding the info method like this

```
class ActiveSupport::BufferedLogger
  _info = instance_method(:info)

  define_method(:info) do |msg|
    _info.bind(self).("#{caller[0]}: " + msg) 
  end
end
```

But it seems to be ignoring my code.

Answer (score 1):

Which version of rails you are using as you will need to monkeypacth *add* method in *BufferedLogger*? so you will need to check the implementation of that version and override it.

As for example for v3.0.0. Create an extension for monkypatching and make sure to run it (ideally in the config/initializer) folder of your rails application, something like:

```
module ActiveSupport
  class BufferedLogger
    def add(severity, message = nil, progname = nil, &block)
      return if @level > severity
      message = (message || (block && block.call) || progname).to_s

      message = "[%s: %s #%d] %s" % ["INFO",
                                     Time.now.strftime("%m%d %H:%M:%S"),
                                     $$,
                                     message]

      message = "#{message}\n" unless message[-1] == ?\n
      buffer << message
      auto_flush
      message
    end
  end
end
```

As you can see it's all about modifying *message* local variable and include whatever you want.

Comment: Will $$, in this case, print the filename and line number from where the logger was called?